What to choose? Popup window or new screen in Android?
I am in a dilemma of choosing whether to use a new screen or a popup window for several similar use cases:

Client management: from a list of clients, click to view client detail or create new client.
Appointment Scheduling: from a screen containing a calendar (weekly or monthly) click on an event to view/edit or create new.

and several others like these..
how do i choose?

There are a few ways to choose, thankfully you don't have any wrong answers just a couple right answers. The optimal answer would actually required some data and testing for you specific app and use case. Here are a few methods I would use if I just wanted to answer this dilemma on my own, quickly without and timely research activities.

Usability Heuristic #4 Consistency and Standards: Is anything similar being displayed through your application or site currently? Sometimes using a behaviour pattern already in place (even if not optimal) is the right choice just because it offers consistency for your users.
What is your User Flow?: Don't look only at the fields on the screen, map out your users' full task, how they got to client management, how they'll interact with it, will they do any back and forth between screens, what will they do next. Looking at the User Flow might even suggest loading a new page on the same screen is appropriate.
Competitive Analysis: What other sites and apps are your users using? Simply matching a model that your users are experience elsewhere is always valid.


Thank you for your answer!
